# How to check if a keyword is present regardless of capitalization?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, keyword

I am writing a program that looks for specific keywords and then only performs an action when a keyword is present in a message. I am having difficulty trying to make it so that it will pickup on keywords regardless of their capitalization. Below is an example of what I currently have.

```
for (var i = 0; i < keyword.length; i++) {

      if (msg.content.includes (keyword[i])) {
      msg.channel.send("Orange")
      }

var keyword = ["Apple","Banana"]
```

The only way I've figured out how to do this is to add each variation to the keyword list. How would I make it so that it could detect for example "apple" or "BaNaNa" without adding those variations to the keyword list?

Comment: use '.toLowerCase()' on both strings and then compare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your message is a string, just make the whole thing lower case and match it to lowercase keywords.

```
let message = msg.content.toLowerCase();
if (message.includes(keyword[i].toLowerCase()) {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert to lowercase both, the database and the search terms.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert both your message and keyword to lowercase and check the existing keyword in your message.

```
if (msg.content.toLowerCase().includes (keyword[i]).toLowerCase()) {
  msg.channel.send("Orange")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have a big string, 'Hello Marco, how are you doing?', and I have another string, 'MarCo', and I want to check if the second string is in the first, I would do

```js
const needle = 'MarCo';
const haystack = 'Hey Marco, how are you doing?'

const inc = haystack.toLowerCase().includes(needle.toLowerCase());
if (inc) {
  console.log('its in there')
} else {
  console.log('not in there');
}
```